# How Can I find DB length in Android DB Table?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am a new on Android and at now I add some Information on database. Finally I want to learn How many Items do I have in my actually table? How can I do? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You may use a database util queryNumEntries (SQLiteDatabase db, String table). The description is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 2):

```
public int getAll(){

    Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {_ID,NAME,
            EMAIL}, null, null, null, null, null);

    int count = cursor.getCount();

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Just code is considered rude, please explain it aswell so that it may help others who come to your answer in future.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I count all of my rows in my `SQLite` database.

```
public int countCases() {

        String SQLQuery = "SELECT COUNT(" + KEY_ID + ") FROM " + TABLE_CASES + ";";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SQLQuery, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int count = cursor.getInt(0);
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return count;
    }
```

Note that `KEY_ID` and `TABLE_CASES` are constant values, also `KEY_ID` is the primary key in my database